# Changing Base View height not changing tableview height iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have a viewcontroller which has tableview as subview. when i try to change the height of the viewcontroller view, tableview height is not changing. but when i manually get the tableview and set it's height. it's working. Here my sample code.

> ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]init];

In ViewController

> UITableview *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init]; // @property,
>    @synthesize are added. tableview frame size is added as view size.
>
> [self.view addSubView:tableVIew];

but when i try to change the ViewController frame. tableview inside ViewController is not changing, it still has original value.

Any Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

This should ensure that the table view gets resized when it's superview's frame changes

Comment: but when i try this code from base view it's working.

NSArray *activeViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *viewController = [activeViewControllers objectAtIndex:activeViewControllers.count-1];

ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)currentViewController;
  vc.tableview.frame = viewController.view.frame;